# grouping of groups (ANOVA)

Tags: anova, group-differences, manova

**Background:** One of my hypothesis' is that several (more than 2) groups (hereafter sub-groups) can be grouped, based on an interval-scaled variable, into two groups that, based on the same interval-scaled variable, are statistically different from each other.

**Assumption:** All conditions for the use of a parametric procedure are met.

**My thought line - thought of methods:**

*Method 1* - Given I can rely on a parametric procedure, I use a single-factor, multivariate (M)ANOVA method to test for differences between the sub-groups. Should I find no significant differences between sub-groups attributable to a group, my hypothesis is verified.

*Method 1a* - Method 1 does not conclude the verification process. I follow Method 1. Given I have verified the first part of my hypothesis (being "groupable"), I test again, using the same method, for differences between groups.

*Method 2* - Or I group sub-groups directly and apply the same outlined method to test for differences between the groups.

**My questions:**

*a)* Should i use single-factor Manova in this process, or would statistical classification or cluster analysis be more appropriate, if any?

*b)* Which method should I choose, if any?

*c)* If method 1a, why would this additional step regarding method 1 be necessary?

*d)* (More general) Given two groups are not statistically different, can I infer from them not being statistically different, that I can group them.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your consideration, though I think I have found an answer to my questions.

From lecture notes i found online (in German; http://www.methodenberatung.uzh.ch/de/datenanalyse/unterschiede/zentral/evarianz.html#K3_3) I take method 1 to be the right choice.

With MANOVA I would find whether there are significant differences between sub-groups (correctly: whether there is an effect of sub-group on interval-scaled variable). Upon further inspection with post-hoc tests i would be able to find out between which sub-groups significant differences exist. According to the notes, if differences between sub-groups are not significant, they may be grouped.